# Differentiating Neo4j queries for different data files

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j 2.1.2. My query is that I have a 3 csv files with the same structure but with different data, say csv1, csv2, csv3. I loaded the csv1 with node and relationship information on Neo4j. Again I loaded csv2 with the same nodename and relationship name as the 1st csv and I did the same thing for csv2 as well.

So when I fire the query without `LOAD CSV` command, then from which file will it file fetch the data? Do we need to add LOAD CSV command each time whenever we want to execute the new query. So how would the query know that the data should be fetched from csv2 only?

Thanks,
Shree

Comment: Make sure to read up in the guide here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Match Command in Neo4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751634/match-command-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 2):

Neo4j is a graph database.

So after you have run your create / merge statements the data is inside the database and you don't need the CSV files from there.

If there is something specific in every CSV file, that needs to be part of your graph model to make it possible to query it.

Please add your domain / graph model to the question, then we can help you with modeling you graph to make it possible to query parts of your database.

Comment: yes even it's clear to me that after load/merge statements the data is going into the database. Here if i load different files with same structure OR if i load different files with different structure, all will be under a single neo4j database? Because in SQL we will be having different databases with many tables, and we will fetch the data by referring to the table. So here in neo4j what is referred to fetch the data?

Comment: Neo4j doesn't have schema's like many Relational databases. Everything will be in one database. Neo4j doesn't have tables, but Nodes. These Nodes can have one or more labels to structure them. Maybe this is a good starting point for you to get more familiar with Neo4j / graph databases: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graphdb-concepts.html

Comment: Also i didn't get domain /graph model. But I'll give one example,suppose i have loaded 2 different files with different nodes and relationships . Say i have created node `A,B,C` after loading file1 and created nodes `X,Y,Z`  after loading files2. So when i fire a query like `MATCH n RETURN n` where n is a NODE. So which nodes are fetched from the database?

Comment: With a graph model I mean: What is the structure of you data. A simple datamodel for facebook can be like: (person1:Person)-[:KNOWS]->(person2:Person)-[:WROTE]->(:TimelineMessage)<-[:LIKES]-(:person1)

For your question about MATCH n RETURN n, this would return all nodes in the database, so from file1 and file2

Comment: thank you, now i got the concept of graph model. Also in the example if i want to get the nodes only from file2, what needs to be done?In my case i have a data model as `CREATE (cname)-[:has]->(clusters),(clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),(Hd)-[:equals]->(DelHd)<-[:assistedby]-(Mgr),(Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp)`

Comment: @shree11 either use `labels` for your nodes (which could be used as an equivalent to schemas in relational dbs), or use one specific root node for each dataset - than, when querying the graph, start with the root node in each `match`

Comment: Creating root node is how different from other nodes? Can you tell me how can i create a root node?

Comment: @shree11 there is no difference, the thing ulkas is trying to say: maybe your model is missing a node to create subgraphs inside your database. Try this model: (root:SubGraph)<-[:PART_OF_SUB_GRAPH]- (cname)-[:has]->(clusters),(clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),(Hd)-‌​[:equals]->(DelHd)<-[:assistedby]-(Mgr),(Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp). Now you can use the root node to filter on you csv file, now called subgraph: I will extend my example here once, cause you are doing the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751634/match-command-in-neo4j