# Match Command in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have two graphs with some nodes with similar labels. If I want to fetch part of a graph  using match command,then do I need to specify the graph name. 
For eg.,
MATCH (dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd)
RETURN count (Hd.name);

I have (dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd) relation in both the graphs, so which data does it fetch?
I'm finding that it is giving me the aggregate count of both the graphs.
Please let me know if I have to pass the graph alias also with the match command and how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

This is the import query to the complete model:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4j\\demo2dbcopy.csv" AS emp 
MERGE (cname:Cmpname {name: emp[0]}) 
MERGE (clusters:ClustName { name: emp [1]}) 
MERGE (dom:domains { name: emp [2]}) 
MERGE (Hd:Head { name: emp [3]}) 
MERGE (DelHd:DeliveryHead { name: emp [4]}) 
MERGE (Mgr:Managers { name: emp [5]}) 
MERGE (Emp:Employees { name: emp [6]}) 
CREATE (cname)-[:has]->(clusters),
       (clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),
      (Hd)-‌​[:equals]->(DelHd),
      (DelHd)-[:assistedby]->(Mgr),
      (Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp) 
return cname,clusters,dom,Hd,DelHd,Mgr,Emp;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this one correctly want to have multiple subgraphs in one Neo4j database.

I think your model is missing a root node for your subgraphs.

Combine your CSV files to one and add 1 column to separate the different subgraphs.
Then the import statement whould look like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4j\\demo2dbcopy.csv" AS emp
MERGE (root:SubGraph {source: emp[7]})
MERGE (cname:Cmpname {name: emp[0]}) 
MERGE (clusters:ClustName { name: emp [1]}) 
MERGE (dom:domains { name: emp [2]}) 
MERGE (Hd:Head { name: emp [3]}) 
MERGE (DelHd:DeliveryHead { name: emp [4]}) 
MERGE (Mgr:Managers { name: emp [5]}) 
MERGE (Emp:Employees { name: emp [6]}) 
CREATE (root)<-[:PART_OF_SUB_GRAPH]-(cname)-[:has]->(clusters),
       (clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),
      (Hd)-‌​[:equals]->(DelHd),
      (DelHd)-[:assistedby]->(Mgr),
      (Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp) 
return root,cname,clusters,dom,Hd,DelHd,Mgr,Emp;
```

You probably want to do something like this:

Find all domains from the sub graph "csv1" and return the count of Heads

```
MATCH (root:SubGraph {source: "csv1"})<--(:Cmpname)-->(:ClustName)-->(dom:domains {name:"foo"})<-[:headedby]-(hd) RETURN dom.name, count (hd.name);
```

**UPDATE: combining the answers of this question en this one here: [Differentiating Neo4j queries for different data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751519/differentiating-neo4j-queries-for-different-data-files)**

Comment: I have the query as: LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4j\\demo2dbcopy.csv" AS emp
MERGE (cname:Cmpname {name: emp[0]})
MERGE (clusters:ClustName { name: emp [1]})
MERGE (dom:domains { name: emp [2]})
MERGE (Hd:Head { name: emp [3]})
MERGE (DelHd:DeliveryHead { name: emp [4]})
MERGE (Mgr:Managers { name: emp [5]})
MERGE (Emp:Employees { name: emp [6]})
CREATE (cname)-[:has]->(clusters),(clusters)-[:contains]->(dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd),(Hd)-[:equals]->(DelHd),(DelHd)-[:assistedby]->(Mgr),(Mgr)-[:Dividesinto]->(Emp)
return cname,clusters,dom,Hd,DelHd,Mgr,Emp;

Comment: for the above query: If I run the above query for two datasets which have different data,the graph is fine. Now if I want to retrieve count(Hd.name) using match command then from which graph it fetches the data. Do I need to specify the graph name or so with match command so that the count from that graph is returned.

Comment: I have added your model to the answer and changed the 2 queries. The queries will run on the complete database. The first query if filtering for a domain with the name:"foo" replace foo with the domain name of your domain. The second query will return all domains found with the count of Heads

Comment: I have ran this query:MATCH (dom)<-[:headedby]-(Hd)
RETURN count (Hd.name); and it gave me 44.   Then I loaded many CSV's using same above posted query with different data and named the graphs with different names.Now if I'm running the same MATCH query,it is giving count as 76....now to get the 1st CSV count i.e., 44 shall I have to specify the graph name i.e.,emp. along with the MATCH command.

Comment: as stated in the answer: you can add {name:"foo"} and replace foo by the name of the domain of you want to have. or run the second query stated in the answer to have a count for every domain in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following query in response to above syntax but it is returning me 0 rows where the correct answer must be 7 rows.

MATCH (root:SubGraph {source: "demo2db"})<--(clusters:ClustName{name:"ABC"})-[:contains]->(dom:domains {name:"XYZ"}) RETURN count(dom.name);